# What's wrong with this jQuery fading gallery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am creating a fading gallery and am a bit of a noob to javascript (but not to programming).  I have no idea what is wrong though.  Here's the function in question:

```
    /*

    */
    function show_next ()
    {
        // Hide current
        $('.s_gallery_images li.s_current').fadeTo(200, .2);

        $('.s_gallery_images li.s_current').css("border","1px green solid");


        //
        if ($('.s_gallery_images li').hasClass ('.s_current'))
        {
            console.log ('Incrementing existing');

            // Class already exists 
            $('.s_current:first').removeClass('s_current').next().addClass('s_current');

            // Was that the last one?
            if ($('.s_gallery_images li').hasClass ('.s_current'))
            {
                console.log ('Current found');
            }
            else
            {
                // Class doesn't exist - add to first
                $('.s_gallery_images li:first').addClass ('.s_current');

                console.log ('Wrapping');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            console.log ('Adding new class');
            // Class doesn't exist - add to first
            $('.s_gallery_images li:first').addClass ('.s_current');
        }

        // Show new marked item
        $('.s_gallery_images li.s_current').fadeTo(200, .8);
    }
```

The HTML is a very simple:

```
<ul class="s_gallery_images">
    <li><img src="imagename" alt="alt" /></li>
    <li><img src="imagename" alt="alt" /></li>
    <li><img src="imagename" alt="alt" /></li>
</ul>
```

And it displays the list and the images fine.  I am using firebugs console.log for debugging, plus have a class set for s_current (bright border) but nothing happens at all.

The firebug console log says:

```
Adding New Class
Incrementing Existing
Current Found
Incrementing Existing
Current Found
Incrementing Existing
Current Found
Incrementing Existing
Current Found
... to infinity
```

The function is called on a setInterval timer, and as far as I can tell it should be working (and I have done something similar before), but it just isn't happening :(

Comment: I think it's probably just something dumb I am not seeing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have some extra dots flying around:

```
.hasClass ('.s_current')
```

`hasClass` just needs the class name, no dot like this: `.hasClass('s_current')`

Same for `addClass`: `.addClass('.s_current')` should be `.addClass('s_current')`

Overall you could shorten the logic a bit as well:

```
function show_next ()
{
  $('.s_gallery_images li.s_current').css("border","1px green solid")
                                     .fadeTo(200, .2);
  if ($('.s_gallery_images li.s_current').length)
      $('.s_current').removeClass('s_current').next().addClass('s_current');
  if(!$('.s_gallery_images li.s_current').length)
      $('.s_gallery_images li:first').addClass('s_current');
  $('.s_gallery_images li.s_current').fadeTo(200, .8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few `.` points too much in a few function calls. The `.classname` syntax is only used for selector syntax, but not when checking/adding/removing class with `hasClass/addClass/removeClass`

`hasClass ('.s_current')` ↯

`hasClass ('s_current')` ✔

`addClass ('.s_current')` ↯

`addClass ('s_current')` ✔